# gdb finds headers from different locations

Tags: boost, gdb

I have two boost header locations L1 and L2. L1 is the default location that gcc can find, while L2 is not. When compiling a shared library, I used -IL2 explicitly.

Two programs P1 and P2 calls the shared lib.

When debugging P1, the headers in L2 are used by GDB. This is expected.
But when debugging P2, the headers in L1 are used by GDB...

I assumed that all debugging symbols and locations are decided at compilation time. If source code is not moved, gdb can find them automatically. And L1 is not in GDB's source path either. How can gdb find different locations?

Answer (score 2):

> How can gdb find different locations?

It is likely that P1 does not *itself* use Boost, but that P2 does.

You can confirm this with `readelf -wl P1 | grep L1` and `readelf -wl P2 | grep L1`.

If the second command results in non-empty output, you have an ODR violation and your program may have a variety of undefined behaviors (including *appearing* to work correctly, but breaking for correct minor changes to the program, or the library).

Comment: I guess P2 uses it. P2 is not an open source program. readelf -wl does not return any symbols. If indeed P2 uses some different boost headers, is there a way to isolate the two boost headers?

Comment: @JoeC GDB doesn't magically invent L1 when debugging P2. If `readelf -wl P2` comes empty, there *must* be some other shared library that references L1. Use `(gdb) info shared` and examine them all.